# Why these many observations are created in the following program?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
    data test;
    infile cards dsd dlm=', .';
    input stmt : $ @@;
    cards;
    T
    ;run;
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
    data test;
    infile cards dsd dlm=', .';
    input stmt : $ @@;
    cards;
    Th
    ;run;
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
    data test;
    infile cards dsd dlm=', .';
    input stmt : $ @@;
    cards;
    This is SAS.
    ;run;
```

When first  program is run, 80 observations are created
When second program is run, 79 observations are created
When third  program is run, 72 observations are created

I know these program has worst programming style. Wrong options are set for wrong technique. DSD option is set, double trailing operator @@ (line holder), Colon modifier (:) are used and more than 1 delimeter is used which is worst SAS programming ever.

Aside from this I want to know why so many observations are created, why 80? 79? how program is executed? I think DSD option & 2 delimeters have major impact. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the combination INFILE and INPUT statement options.  You don't "need" the colon modifier since you are not using an in-format, $ alone is not an in-format, but your program works the same either way.  While the combination of options may seem odd and with fixed-length records you get and unexpected number of observations I don't see anything to make it worst program ever.

Comment: @data_null_ i felt that way because nobody would use these many options just to read single character... :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get more records than you expect is because CARDS are fixed length records.   The reason you get a difference number of records is because there is a different number of null fields left after reading the non-null field(s).  You can see this by adding the COL option to the INFILE statement to show you where the column pointer is after reading each field. Col=3, 4 , 13

```
data test;
infile cards dsd dlm=', .' col=c;
input stmt : $ @@;
col=c;
cards;
T
;run;
proc print data=test(obs=5);
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
data test;
infile cards dsd dlm=', .' col=c;
input stmt : $ @@;
col=c;
cards;
Th
;run;
proc print data=test(obs=5);
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
data test;
infile cards dsd dlm=', .' col=c;
input stmt : $ @@;
col=c;
cards;
This is SAS.
;run;
proc print data=test(obs=5);
run;
```

[image]

Comment: you mentioned that "different number of null fields left after reading the non-null field(s)"..why its around 80.... there are no null fields in the cards...only 1 or 2 characters...I think input buffer takes record's default length as 80..what do you think?

Comment: You have MANY null fields each space (one of your delimiters) defines a null field.  Yes the input buffer is 80 for CARDS input (most of the fime), the source of all those null fields.  Alternatively you can use PARMCARDS for in-stream data, SAS will put the in-stream data into a file defined by the FILEREF named in the PARMCARDs system option (default FT15F001) which can be read using RECFM=V, to produce the result you expect.